# How to make this circle in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uistoryboard

How to make this circle in iOS ? I am using Swift and don't know how to create outer circle in the image given below.

[image]

Comment: Please check the site FAQ's. Show what you have tried already and explain why they aren't working. this is not a free code writing service. explain your issue and your approach and we will help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to have 2 layers. The base layer will be transparent and bigger than the upper layer which is the your instance of UIImageView.

Then you can set the base layer a border with cornerRadius 50% of its width as same as your image view. cornerRadius will be accessible on your layer interface.

```
let radius = imageView.frame.size.width * 0.5
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = radius
```

Finally you can set the border of your base layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer to draw a circle on UIImageView.

Please check code:

```
    let center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 90.0, startAngle: ((.pi * -90.0) / 180), endAngle: ((.pi * 360.0) / 180), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.borderWidth = 1.0
    shapeLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Hope it works for you!